# Analytic functions on spaces over non-Archimedean fields and troubles with totally disconnectedness

Tags: analytic-geometry, analytic-functions, nonarchimedian-analysis, rigid-analytic-spaces

I read in several intro scripts on Berkovish spaces that these
arose as new approach to analytic geometry
over non-archimedean fields. As the main problem in
non-archimedean analytic geometry is recognized the
observation that analytic functions
cannot simply be defined as functions that are given locally by a
power series (like eg in case of field $\mathbb{C}$),
due to the space being totally disconnected.

The last part I not understand. Why totally
disconnectedness of the spaces causes big troubles if one tries
to study the space using naively defined analytic functions
on it locally expressible in power series? I not see any reason why such functions cannot be defined also over non-archimedean fields.

Comment: The function $\forall a\in \Bbb{Z}_2,f(2a) = 0,f(1+2a)=1$ is given locally by a power series on $\Bbb{Z}_2$ but it is clearly not analytic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly suggest reading Andre's [book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203194.pdf).

Let us say that a sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ on a topological space $X$ is *non-degenerate* if whenever $U\subseteq X$ is a non-empty open subset, one has that $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is non-zero. This assumption is completely reasonable if, for instance, you desire that $\mathcal{O}(U)$ should contain 'all constant functions on $U$' (where this is intentionally vague, but is clear in all examples).

So, let us make the following trivial observation

> **Claim:** If $\mathcal{O}$ is non-degenerate and $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is an integral domain (or more specifically 'connected' -- i.e. that $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}(X))$ is connected) then $X$ is connected.

*Proof:*  Indeed, suppose that $X=U\sqcup V$ where $U,V\subseteq X$ are open. Then, $\mathcal{O}(X)=\mathcal{O}(U)\times\mathcal{O}(V)$ and by our assumption on $\mathcal{O}(X)$ we see that $\mathcal{O}(U)$ or $\mathcal{O}(V)$ is zero, and so one of $U$ or $V$ is empty. $\blacksquare$

So then, where is the issue with disconnectedness in rigid geometry? Let $K$ be a non-archimedean field (maybe algebraically closed for total realism) and let us denote

$$\mathbb{B}^1(K):=\{x\in K: |x|\leqslant 1\},$$

endowed with the subspace topology of $K$ (where $K$ itself is given the topology associated to $|\cdot|$). One then wants to define a *sheaf of analytic functions* $\mathcal{O}$ on $\mathbb{B}^1(K)$ and one expects that

1. one has the equality $$\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{B}^1(K))=K\langle x\rangle:=\left\{\sum_n a_n x^n : \lim |a_n|=0\right\},$$
   the *ring of convergent (on the unit ball) power series*,
2. for all non-empty open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{B}^1(K)$ one has that $\mathcal{O}(U)$ contains the set of constant functions $U\to K$ (and in-particular is non-zero).

From 2. we see that $\mathcal{O}$ is non-degenerate, but as $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{B}^1(K))$ is an integral domain by 1. this is a contradiction as $\mathbb{B}^1(K)$ is **highly disconnected** as $K$ is non-archimedean.

**PS:** At this point there are many flavors of rigid geometry: Tate, Raynaud, Berkovich, Huber, Fujiwara--Kato,... and all of them aim to 'fix' this problem in one way or another. Saying that Berkovich was the first to do so is anachronistic, although Berkovich's approach was the first to fix this problem by *modifying the space $\mathbb{B}^1(K)$* (to what is called $\mathbb{B}^{1,\mathrm{Berk}}$) in a literal sense opposed to the more indirect sense of Tate (i.e. having $\mathcal{O}$ only be defined on certain 'admissible opens' in $\mathbb{B}^1(K)$).

Comment: so intitively one could say the problem is that there 'too many' disjoint open subsets, leading the naive approaches to establish sheaves on these to contradictions? Also I found in this one (1.3.12) enlightening: https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/j.nicaise/document/661/lecture_notes_LSGNT/?lecture_notes_LSGNT.pdf In classical algebraic geometry the intention behind introducing sheaf apparatus is sincerly study global objects locally and often the hope is that local analysis provides enough information to reconstruct the global one. but here we have too many open subsets and study the

Comment: behavior of the global object on just a couple of them not suffice since there is no 'analytic continuation' pendant available. think that's also an important point

Comment: @user7391733 Again, I would suggest reading Andre's book.